# Make a div class for a img button

Tags: html, css, image, class

sorry if my title is a bit misleading but didn't know how to word/phrase it.

Currently, I have href'd images that go to various social networks. For example, by clicking on the facebook icon, it goes to my facebook. It is layed out like this:

```
<div class="row">
            <center>
                <div class="span2">
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/XXXXXXX" target="_blank"><img src="assets/img/icons/fbwhitebig.png" width="64" height="64"></img></a> 
                </div>
```

Is there a way to make this a "class" if that makes sense? So I can get the same effect by doing something like

```
<div class="span2">
<a href=http://www.facebook.com/XXXXXX" target="_blank" class="facebookbutton"></a>
</div>
```

and then in the CSS have this:

```
.facebookbutton {
    width:64px;
    height64px;
    background: url(assets/img/snicons/fbwhitebig.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Sorry if this is a ridiculous post, I'm still learning haha!

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried the code you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

If you fix the typos (the missing opening quote after href= and missing colon after height), and add `display: block` the code you wrote works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/oudL3ovz/1/

```
.facebookbutton {
    width:64px;
    height:64px;
    background: url("http://s10.postimg.org/l40wid7mt/facebook_logo_64px.png") no-repeat;
    display:block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="span2">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/XXXXXX" target="_blank" class="facebookbutton"></a>
</div>
```

You may want to use `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: Just then out of curiosity, can the background: url be an image from within my code directories like it is when I use the <img>? So background: url(assets/img/snicons/facebookbutton.png) no-repeat;?

Comment: Why don't you try that? It needs to be an absolute URL or relative to the .css file, not to the page.

Comment: I've managed to get it to work, however I can't seem to resize it.

http://jsfiddle.net/oudL3ovz/2/

When set to 512x512px, it displays the image fine, as the image size is 512x512. However if I want the image to display as 64x64, and change the width and height px to 64 it doesn't scale the image down, only displays a corner of it thus making it not visible.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Yes. What have you tried / searched the internet for?

Comment: Do you mean in terms of image or CSS image resizing?

Comment: To fix the latest problem you have with image resizing.

Comment: I found:-  background-size: 64px 64px;, so I've set my code as:-

.facebookbutton {
    width:512px;
    height:512px;
    background: url(../img/snicons/fbwhitebig.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 64px 64px;
    display:block;
}

But it still displays the 512x512 image.

Comment: Not sure why you have width and height set to 512px but `background-size: 64px 64px` should work. Maybe not in the browser you're using. I'm going to delete this answer because it answers the question but instead of accepting and posting another question you're adding to it.